# How remove `text-decoration: line-through` from the button in library react-editext?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I use library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-editext. I try to remove `text-decoration: line-through` from the edit button, and when I press the edit button from the cancel and submit buttons. It tries to give the buttons `text-decoration: none !important` style, but the strikethrough does not disappear from the buttons.

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dmfbqc

Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGBoC.jpg

**CSS**

```
.lineThrough {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.styles_Editext__button__6H8n_, .styles_Editext__edit_button__hthOZ {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.styles_Editext__save_button__3WN6q {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.styles_Editext__cancel_button__259hb {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

**javascript**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';
import EdiText from 'react-editext'


class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  onSave = val => {
   console.log('Edited Value -> ', val)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="lineThrough">
        <EdiText
          type="text"
          value='What is real? How do you define real?'
          onSave={this.onSave}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where is the rest of your imports? what gets shown in when you execute your code? is your onSave function declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This ::

css file ::

```
 h1, p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.lineThrough__none > :first-child {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
.lineThrough__none {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

index js ::

```
<div>
        <EdiText
          type="text"
          value='What is real? How do you define real?'
          viewContainerClassName='lineThrough__none'
          onSave={this.onSave}
        />
      </div>
```

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ntqzyc?file=index.js

Output here : https://react-ntqzyc.stackblitz.io/

Comment: And you could do it so that when I click edit, the inscription in input will not be line-through?

Comment: change css like this :: h1, p {
  font-family: Lato;
}
.styles_Editext__input__1534X{
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
.lineThrough__none >  :first-child {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

Answer (score 1):

It could be that :

1. You have not imported everything needed in your `.js` file.
2. Or you have not defined your `onSave()` function . something like : `onSave = val => {
   console.log('Edited Value -> ', val)
   }`

Comment: I updated my code.  Read the question. I want to remove `text-decoration: line-through`  from the edit button

Comment: Only the inscription "What is real? How do you define real?" is to be line-through